# How do i find out the parent element of XML from a textFrame paragraph with indesign scripting

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I have TextFrames tagged with a script label and the paragraphs inside the text frame are having a paragraph label and some paragraphs are grouped together in the XML and given a tag name. I am trying to match the script label to the XML structure of the document to understand which paragraph needs to be placed in which particular TextFrame to do that I am iterating across all the paragraphs and then searching for the parent XML element but its inturn giving me the document root.

Sample code:

```
// to get the parent markup tag name
TextFrame.paragraphs[2].associatedXMLElements[0].parent.markupTag.name
// this works perfectly for to get the markup for a given paragraph
TextFrame.paragraphs[2].associatedXMLElements[0].markupTag.name
```

documentation of paragraph and associatedXMLElements has both parent to extract the markup tag name

[Paragraph - Indesing Scripting](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5js/pc_Paragraph.html)

[pc_XMLItem - Indesing Scripting](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5js/pc_XMLItem.html)

I am not sure if I am missing something,

I did try the [Glue Code.jsx](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skilldrick/InDesign-Scripts/master/glue%20code.jsx) to extract the XML tags but I would like to get it from the paragraph of a text frame as the glue code has no inference on the layout of the page with text frames and it will provide the entire structure.

---

For example:

```
- Chapter
 - C1
 - C2
 - C3
  - C3-1
  - C3-2
 - C4
 - C5
```

Assuming all these paragraphs are there in a textFrame named `TextFrame`
No iam going through all the paragraphs as

```js
for (eachP = 0; eachP < TextFrame.paragraphs.length; eachP++) {
    allAssociatedXMLElements = TextFrame.paragraphs[eachP].associatedXMLElements.length
    for (eachAsXML = 0; eachAsXML < allAssociatedXMLElements; eachAsXML++) {
        $.writeln(TextFrame.paragraphs[eachP].associatedXMLElements[eachAsXML].markupTag.name)
    }
$.witeln(" -- ")
}
```

This gives me

```
Chapter
C1
 -- 
Chapter
C2
 -- 
Chapter
 -- 
C3
C3-2
 -- 
Chapter
C4
 -- 
Chapter
C5
```

`XML Structure`

```xml
<C1>Content1</C1>¶
<C2>Content2</C2>¶
<C3>
    <C3-1>Content5</C3-1>¶
    <C3-2>Content6</C3-2>¶
</C3>
<C4>Content3</C4>¶
<C5>Content4</C5>¶
```

Not sure why it is not getting the root for `C3-1`, Someone please let me know if iam doing it wrong somewhere.

Comment: try replacing "parent" with another associatedXMLElements 
 
 
TextFrame.paragraphs[2].associatedXMLElements[0].associatedXMLElements[0].markupTag.name

Comment: Even that throws an error: `Error: Object does not support the property or method 'associatedXMLElements'`

Comment: Can you provide your looping code and the example XML?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60096112/how-to-group-xml-elements-in-in-design-by-adding-them-to-a-parent-tag You could this example and to find out the parent for `EL2` in the expected result.

Comment: @EdLucas I am not sure what did you mean by looping code.

Comment: @SundeepPidugu From your question: " I am iterating across all the paragraphs".

Comment: Iam simply getting all the paragraphs with `textframe.paragraphs.length` and then iterating over each paragraph with `textframe.paragraphs[i]` and then trying to get the XML nodes.

Comment: @EdLucas added an example in the question please check.

Comment: @SundeepPidugu It's still a bit hard to follow what's going on without seeing your original XML.

Comment: @EdLucas i have added the `XML` for the chapter in the question.