# How to group XML elements in in-design by adding them to a parent tag

Tags: javascript, xml, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I have XML elements linked to the root element of the document and there are some elements that should be grouped and then linked to the design document, So I would like to know how I can create a virtual group and add the elements to a parent tag that will, in turn, be the child of the parent in InDesign scripting

Existing :

```
-EL1
-EL2
-EL3
-EL4
-EL5
```

Expected:

```
-EL1
-EL
--EL2
--EL3
--EL4
-EL5
```

Where `EL` is the parent and `EL2,EL3,EL4` are the child elements.

Comment: What's the criteria for choosing which elements should be added to the new parent element/tag - is it based on their element/tag name, their position, or something else? What's the criteria for naming the newly created parent element/tag?

Comment: for example, it could be the elements from 2 to 4 and then the parent name is the first two characters of the elements selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Setup a demo .indd

To provide some context for this answer, and to aid explanation and demonstration, firstly import the following XML document into a new inDesign document:

**sample.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
  <EL1>Para 1</EL1>
  <EL2>Para 2</EL2> 
  <EL3>Para 3</EL3> 
  <EL4>Para 4</EL4> 
  <EL5>Para 5</EL5>
  <EL6>Para 6</EL6>
  <EL7>Para 7</EL7>
  <EL8>Para 8</EL8>
  <EL9>Para 9</EL9>
</Root>
```

To import the `sample.xml` into a new document follow these steps:

1. Create a new InDesign document.
2. Select `View` > `Structure` > `Show Structure` from the Menu Bar to reveal the *XML  Structure* panel.
3. In the *XML  Structure* panel select the default `Root` XML element.
4. In the *XML  Structure* panel choose `Import XMl` from the dropdown menu.
5. Locate the aforementioned `sample.xml` file and open it.
6. Finally save the document

<sub>**Note:** Throughout this answer we'll need to revert the `.indd` file back to this starting state - so please ensure you save it.</sub>

The documents XML tree should now be structured as follows:

**Initial XML tree structure:**

```
Root
├── EL1
├── EL2
├── EL3
├── EL4
├── EL5
├── EL6
├── EL7
├── EL8
└── EL9
```

As you can see it's very similar to what you described in your question, however there's just a few more elements, namely; `EL6`, `EL7`,`EL8`, `EL9`.

---

### Solution A

**example-a.jsx**

```js
#target indesign

// 1. Obtain a reference to the active document.
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// 2. Obtain a reference to the root element 
var root = doc.xmlElements.item(0);

// 3. Create a new tag
var newParentTag = doc.xmlTags.add("EL");

// 4. Create a new element node
var parentNode = root.xmlElements.add(newParentTag.name);

// 5. Change the position of the newly created element node
parentNode.move(LocationOptions.before, root.xmlElements.item(1));

// 6. Move elements to be children of the newly created parent element.
root.xmlElements.item(4).move(LocationOptions.atBeginning, root.xmlElements.item(1));
root.xmlElements.item(3).move(LocationOptions.atBeginning, root.xmlElements.item(1));
root.xmlElements.item(2).move(LocationOptions.atBeginning, root.xmlElements.item(1));
```

If we run the code provided in `example-a.jsx` (above) it will restructure the XML tree to the following:

**XML tree structure after:**

```
Root
├── EL1
├── EL
│   ├── EL2
│   ├── EL3
│   └── EL4
├── EL5
├── EL6
├── EL7
├── EL8
└── EL9
```

<sub>**Note:** Before proceeding to *Solution B* (below) please revert the demo inDesign document to it's original state. Select `File` > `Revert` from the Menu Bar.</sub>

---

### Solution B

If you intend to restructure the XML tree often, i.e. you intent to move various child elements to a new parent element often, then I would consider utilizing a helper function such as the `childElementsToNewParent` function shown below. By doing this you can provide a simpler interface for performing this task.

**example-b.jsx**

```js
#target indesign

$.level=0;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Usage
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// 1. Obtain a reference to the active document.
var doc = app.activeDocument;


// 2. Obtain a reference to the root element
var rootElement = doc.xmlElements.item(0);


// 3. Restructure the XML tree.
childElementsToNewParent(doc, rootElement, 2, 4);


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Helpers
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Moves child element(s) at a given position within a given parent element to
 * a new parent element.
 *
 * @param {Object} doc - A document reference for changing its XML structure.
 * @param {Object} parent - The parent XMlElement whose children need to move.
 * @param {Number} from - The position of the first child element to move.
 * @param {Number} to - The position of the last child element to move.
 * @param {Object} options - The configuration options.
 * @param {String} [options.tagName=undefined] - A custom name for the newly
 *  created parent XML element.
 */
function childElementsToNewParent(doc, parent, from, to, options) {

  // Default options
  var opts = {
    tagName: undefined
  }

  // Override the default opts with any user defined options.
  opts = assign(options, opts);

  var xPath = '*[position() >= ' + from + ' and position() <= ' + to + ']';

  var childrenToMove = parent.evaluateXPathExpression(xPath);

  // XMLElements matched by the `evaluateXPathExpression` method are returned
  // in any order. We sort each element object in the array by it positional
  // index to ensure that when we move them to a new parent element their
  // positional order is preserved as-is.
  childrenToMove = sortArrayOfObjects(childrenToMove, 'index');

  var firstChildToMove = childrenToMove[0];
  var firstChildToMoveIndex = firstChildToMove.index;

  var xmlTagName = opts.tagName
      ? opts.tagName
      : firstChildToMove.markupTag.name.substring(0, 2);

  createXmlTag(doc, xmlTagName);

  // Move the newly created parent XMLElement to
  // before the first child element to be moved.
  parent.xmlElements.add(xmlTagName).move(
    LocationOptions.before,
    parent.xmlElements.item(firstChildToMoveIndex)
  );

  // Move each the matched child XMLElement(s) into their new parent XMLElement.
  for (var i = 0, max = childrenToMove.length; i < max; i++) {
    childrenToMove[i].move(
      LocationOptions.atEnd,
      parent.xmlElements.item(firstChildToMoveIndex)
    );
  }
}

/**
 * Enumerates own properties of a 'source' object and copies them to a 'target'
 * object. Properties in the 'target' object are overwritten by properties in
 * the 'source' object if they have the same key.
 *
 * @param {Object} source - The object containing the properties to apply.
 * @param {Object} target - The object to apply the source object properties to.
 * @returns {Object} - The target object.
 */
function assign(source, target) {
  if (typeof source === 'object') {
    for (key in source) {
      if (source.hasOwnProperty(key) && target.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        target[key] = source[key];
      }
    }
  }
  return target;
}

/**
 * Sorts array of objects by value of property name in ascending order.
 *
 * @param {Array} arr - The array of objects to sort.
 * @param {String} prop - The name of the object property to sort by.
 * @returns {Array} - Array of objects sorted by value of property name.
 */
function sortArrayOfObjects(arr, prop) {
  return arr.sort(function sortByPropertyValue(a, b) {
    if (a[prop] < b[prop]) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
}

/**
 * Creates a new XML tag if the given name does not already exist.
 *
 * @param {String} tagName - The name of the XML tag.
 * @param {Object} doc - A reference to the document to add the XMl tag to.
 */
function createXmlTag(doc, tagName) {
  var hasTag = inArray(tagName, doc.xmlTags.everyItem().name);
  if (! hasTag) {
    doc.xmlTags.add(tagName);
  }
}


/**
 * Determines whether an array includes a certain value among its elements.
 *
 * @param {String} valueToFind - The value to search for.
 * @param {Array} arrayToSearch - The array to search in.
 * @returns {Boolean} true if valueToFind is found within the array.
 */
function inArray(valueToFind, arrayToSearch) {
  for (var i = 0, max = arrayToSearch.length; i < max; i++) {
    if (arrayToSearch[i] === valueToFind) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

If we run the code provided in `example-a.jsx` (above) it will restructure the XML tree to the same resultant structure as shown in the *"XML tree structure after"* section of *"Solution A"*.

<sub>**Note:** Don't revert the `indd` document just yet - leave it as-is for the following usage example to be relevant.</sub>

#### Another example of using `example-b.jsx`

Let's say we now want to restructure the tree from the previously shown *"XML tree structure after"* state to the following state:

**The next desired XML tree structure:**

```
Root
├── EL1
├── EL
│   ├── EL2
│   └── section
│       ├── EL3
│       └── EL4
├── EL5
├── EL6
├── EL7
├── EL8
└── EL9
```

To achieve this structure we need to replace the the following line:

```js
// 3. Restructure the XML tree.
childElementsToNewParent(doc, rootElement, 2, 4);
```

...that is currently defined in `example-b.jsx`, i.e. the line that invokes the `childElementsToNewParent` function, with the following two lines instead:

```
var parentElement = rootElement.xmlElements.item(1);
childElementsToNewParent(doc, parentElement, 2, 3, { tagName: 'section' });
```

This time we are essentially:

1. Obtaining a reference to the `EL` element (as that's the parent element containing the child elements we want to move) and assigning it to a variable named `parentElement`.
2. Invoking the `childElementsToNewParent` function with the following arguments:

   - `doc` - A reference to the document that we want to change its XML structure.
   - `parentElement` - The variable whose value is a reference to the `EL` element.
   - `2` - The first position of the child element that we want to move.
   - `3` - The last position of the child element that we want to move.
   - `{ tagName: 'section' }` - An `options` object which includes a key/property named `tagName` with a value of `section`.

**Note:** This time we passed an optional `options` object that specified the name for the newly created parent element, namely `section`. When invoking the `childElementsToNewParent` function without providing a value for `tagName` in the the `options` object we infer the name for the new parent element by using the first two characters of the first child element to be move. As per your comment:

> ... the parent name is the first two characters of the elements selected

**Additional note**

You'll have noticed in that last example we obtained a reference to the `EL` element, (i.e. the reference to the parent element containing the child elements that we wanted to move), by utilizing the following notation;

```js
var parentElement = rootElement.xmlElements.item(1);
```

... which can get get rather long when wanting to obtain a reference to a deeply nested element. You'll end up doing something like this:

```js
var parentElement = rootElement.xmlElements.item(1).xmlElements.item(3).xmlElements.item(1) ....
```

I prefer utilizing the [`evaluateXPathExpression`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_XMLElement.html#evaluateXPathExpression) method instead as this allows us to match the element using an [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression. For example to obtain the reference to the `EL` element we could do this instead

```js
var parentElement = rootElement.evaluateXPathExpression('EL')[0];
```

As you can see, we're also utilizing the `evaluateXPathExpression` method in the body of the `childElementsToNewParent` function to obtain a reference to the child elements that we want to move:

> ```js
> var xPath = '*[position() >= ' + from + ' and position() <= ' + to + ']';
>
> var childrenToMove = parent.evaluateXPathExpression(xPath);
> ```

<sub>This expression utilizes XPath's [`position()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) function to find the child elements within the given positional range. It's essentially the positional range you define when passing the `from` and `to` arguments to the `childElementsToNewParent` function.</sub>

Comment: I was trying the second approach and i would like to know how do I retain the paragraph breaks and styles after linking/grouping(As you did in the example) the child elements to a parent element

Comment: When you tag paragraph(s) using inDesign you need to ensure that the hidden paragraph break character (`¶`) is inside the closing tag and then you will retain the paragraph breaks and style when restructuring the XML tree. For example, if you firstly select  `Type` > `Show Hidden Characters` from the menu bar and then `Edit` > `Edit in Layout` from the menu bar. You should ensure that you see the `¶` hidden character located something like this: `<EL2>Some text¶</EL2>`, and _not_ this <EL2>Some text</EL2>¶` before running the script. If your markup indicates the latter, it's becomes very...

Comment: difficult to automate. You'll need to utilize the [`insertTextAsContent`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_XMLElement.html#insertTextAsContent) method in your code, something like this: `childrenToMove[i].insertTextAsContent('\r', XMLElementPosition.ELEMENT_END)` to add new paragraph breaks. But as I said, determining the correct logic for when and not to insert new paragraph breaks becomes very difficult. Btw. you'll notice that inDesign looses the paragraph breaks and styling when your markup is `<EL2>Some text</EL2>¶` and you do this restructuring manually.